# Javascript hide the context

Tags: javascript, node.js

What's the best way for a method to call another method and pass the arguments in not-by-reference fashion?

i.e.

```
function main() {
    let context = {};
    // Pass context to someOtherFunction
    // Such that console.log(context) in this function does not show `{whatever: true}`
}

function someOtherFunc(context) {
    context.whatever = true;
}
```

I realize I can clone the `context` and pass that. But I was wondering if there was another way to do this, maybe using anonymous function wrap?

Comment: Why would it produce `{x: true}`?

Comment: @AndrewLi Because I thought the context would be separated

Comment: But you are passing in an object and modifying it? Why would it *not* be modified?

Comment: Alright then let me rephrase it then: how do I separate the context of the parent from the child?

Comment: What do you mean by "parent" and "child"?

Comment: Anonymous functions have their own context, so yes, you can separate them. In you case you're shadowing the variable `x` of the parent's context within the context of the function, but the value of the inner `x` is the same as the outer `x`, as you passed the same object to the function.

Comment: you want to copy the variable sent to the function, not its reference, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`

Comment: Hard to imagine this question being expressed in a more confusing way (given that the term 'context' has a specific meaning, and you are just talking about a random variable/passed parameter). If you want to write code like this and leave the passed parameter unchanged, you will want to clone the object which is passed in. @mh-cbon provides one way, you could also use lodash if you want a shallow copy. I might suggest you step back and think about whether you may want to take a different general approach to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's break this down a bit

```
const context = {x: true};
```

Above, you create an object (named context) in the global scope.

```
function(x) {
    "use strict";
    x.y = true;
}
```

You create an anonymous function that takes a reference to an object, and adds a new property `y` to that object

```
(/*...*/)(context);
```

You wrapped the above function into an IIFE so it immediately executes.  For the parameter, you supplied a reference to the global `context` object, which is referenced by `x` inside the IIFE.

Objects are passed around by reference.  Passing `context` in to the function doesn't create a new object `x` that is a copy of the `context`, it creates a new reference `x` that references the same object that `context` references.

If you need to actually copy the provided object into a new object, you need to do that yourself.  As mentioned above, one mechanism is to stringify the object into JSON and then parse the JSON back to a new object.  There are others depending on what you need to accomplish.

This isn't even a scope or context question at all - it's passing a reference to an object in to a function.  Even if your IIFE had no way whatsoever of directly accessing the `context` variable, once you pass a reference to that object as an input to the function, the function has the reference and can do what it likes to it.

You also seem to misunderstand about how IIFEs hide data.  You hide things **inside** the IIFE from things **outside**, not vice versa.  Even then, it won't prevent you from passing a reference outside of the IIFE. Here's an example:

```
function changeName(animal) {
    "use strict"
    //myDog.name = "Rex"; // Error - myDog isn't a valid reference in this scope
    //myCat.name = "Rex"; // Error - myCat isn't a valid reference in this scope either 
    animal.name = "Rex";  // Perfectly legal
}

(function () {
    var myDog = {name: "Rover"};
    var myCat = {name: "Kitty"};

    console.log(myDog);
    console.log(myCat);
    changeName(myDog);  // Even though changeName couldn't directly access myDog, if we give it a reference, it can do what it likes with it.
    console.log(myDog);
})()
```

In this case, `changeName` has no access to `myDog` or `myCat` which are purely contained within the closure formed by the IIFE.  However, the code that exists within that IIFE is able to pass a reference to myDog to changeName and allow it to change the name of the dog, even though changeName still couldn't access the object using the `myDog` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not technically redefining x, but adding properties to it.

Comment: I thought the whole point of anonymous functions were to separate the context.

Comment: Well, if you want to separate context, you could use sub objects, e.g. context = {x:{x:true}, y:{y:true}, and then do context.x or context.y

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood where your doubts came from so this is *(to the best of my knowledge)* an explanation of what your code is doing.

I'll try to translate the code to human-english.

Define the variable `context` in the "global scope". *(It can be read from anywhere)*

*It cannot be redefined because its a constant.*

Afterwards, define an anonymous self-invoking function *(which "starts" a new "local scope" above the global scope so it has access to everything the global scope had access to)*

This self invoking function grabs parameter `x` and adds the property `y` with a value of `true` to `x` and calls itself with the variable `context`

Read the value of `context`.

**Please read:**

- [**JavaScript Scope**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)
- [**JavaScript Function Definitions**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) *(Self-Invoking Functions)*